# Finding new convert issuances

Tags: convertible-bond

What is the best way to find new convert bond issuances? I have access to a Bloomberg terminal and google, and between the two I feel I ought to be able to find new issuances, but I can't. Every time I  try to search NEWI's on google I get weird articles about total convert issuance numbers for 2017 in USD and other such things that don't give me a list of companies to look at. Just macro stuff I'm not interested in at the moment. I've asked a lot of places so hopefully I can get something here. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

NIM5 , will pull up equity linked securities and you can input a date range if you toggle the Issue History radio button.